# How to get the file path and file name of image captured from firefox camera in Firefox OS (ZTE device)

Tags: firefox-os

I am using Web activity to launch default Firefox camera from my web app in Firefox OS. Able to launch default Firefox camera and took picture. Got `this.result` as return value inside pick success.

Now I need to get file path, where image get saved and also image file name.

Tried to parse the `this.result.blob`, but couldn't find the path or file related parameter .

Below is the code I'm using

```
var activity = new MozActivity({
  // Ask for the "pick" activity
  name: "pick",

  // Provide the data required by the filters of the activity
  data: {
    type: "image/jpeg"
  }
});

activity.onsuccess = function() {
  var picture = this.result;
  console.log("A picture has been retrieved");
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The image file name is not returned, as you can see [from the code](https://github.com/mozilla-b2g/gaia/blob/master/apps/camera/js/controllers/activity.js#L282). If you would need the file name (I can't really think of a very good use case to be honest) you can iterate over the pictures storage in the [DeviceStorageAPI](https://wiki.mozilla.org/WebAPI/DeviceStorageAPI) and get the last saved file. It's probably the one from the camera (compare blobs to be totally sure).

Answer (score 0):

In your success handler, you will get the file name if you use:

```
this.result.blob.name
```

And, you can get the path to the file as:

```
window.URL.createObjectURL(this.result.blob);
```

[Source](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2013/01/introducing-web-activities/)